# Upgrade from Angular 5.2 to 7 broke Post methods

Tags: angular, typescript, http

> Argument of type '(error: HttpErrorResponse) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught:
>   Observable>) => ObservableInput'.   Type
>   'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'

```
GetFullAddress(addressModel: FullAddressLookupModel): Observable<AddressModel> {
    return this.httpClient.post<AddressModel>(this.Domain + "api/addressSearch/confirmAddressSelection",
        JSON.stringify(addressModel), this.httpOptions ).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}



private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Comment: `handleError` doesn't  seem to return the expected return value.

Comment: Hum, catcherror need an object like ```catchError((err) => { console.error('Error :', err.message}); ``` or ```catchError((err) => { this.handleError(err)}); ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public GetFullAddress(addressModel: FullAddressLookupModel): Promise<AddressModel> {
    const promise: Promise<AddressModel> = new Promise<AddressModel>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.httpClient.post<AddressModel>(`${this.Domain}api/addressSearch/confirmAddressSelection`, JSON.stringify(addressModel), this.httpOptions ).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )).toPromise().then((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Below error comes
[image]

Comment: Argument of type 'HttpEvent<AddressModel>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AddressModel | PromiseLike<AddressModel>'.
  Type 'HttpSentEvent' is not assignable to type 'AddressModel | PromiseLike<AddressModel>'.
    Property 'then' is missing in type 'HttpSentEvent' but required in type 'PromiseLike<AddressModel>

Comment: Sorry, used http instead of httpClient - try now

Comment: I was using the httpClient